# Boolean algebra simplification a'bc+ab'c+abc'+abc

Tags: boolean-algebra

Can't figure out how to simplify $(^\neg a)bc+a(^\neg b)c+ab(^\neg c)+abc$, I'm really bad at this...

Comment: Do you know what a Karnaugh map is?

Comment: No clue, are just working with boolean algebra identities like de Morgan's law

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a'bc+ab'c+abc'+abc = a'bc+a(b'c+bc'+bc)$

Let's continue:

$a'bc+a*(b'c+bc'+bc)=a'bc+a(b'c+b(c'+c))=a'bc+a(b'c+b)=a'bc+ab'c+ab$

Why don't you try to see if you can simplify further (which I doubt is possible).

Comment: I'm really confused as to how you completed the first step

Comment: with numbers, $6+8+10=2(3+4+5)$. this is a similar concept. $ab'c+abc'+abc=a(b'c+bc'+bc)$. because $a$ appears in every term.

Comment: $(x+x'y) = (x + y)$

Comment: Please read, Oria, [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?r=SearchResults&s=2|143.1568).  Consider yourself fully informed.  You answered a very low quality answer, and fully.  This violates quality standards on this site, so be aware of the consequences of repeatedly doing so.

Answer (score 0):

A'B C + A B'C + A B C'+ A B C

Since We can use ABC = ABC + ABC So I use three of Copies:

A'B C + A B'C + A B C' + A B C + A B C + A B C

RE-ARRANGE:
A'B C + A B C + A B'C + A B C + A B C'+A B C

GROUPING: 
BC(A'+A) + AC(B'+B) + AB(C'+C)

Since A'+A=1 & B'+B=1 & C'+C=1;

= BC+AC+AB

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. You can type mathematical formulas in a beautiful way using MathJax. [Here's](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial.